# Skype client's (group) chat not working

Tags: 13.10, skype

Ubuntu 13.10, Skype client 4.2.0.13

When installed the Skype client first it worked as expected (5 months ago). But for around two weeks I can't see some group chats (some I can see others I can't!) anymore. I tried re-installing with deleting of the local profile (~/.Skype) without success. Since that is not the source of the problem, I would think that it might be due to a recent system update.. but have no idea what I should do to fix this.

Any known fixes or am I the only one with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boring answer: Updating to the latest Skype of the version 4.3 solved the issue.

Previous updates from the 4.2.X line had no consequence. Probably this issue was really connected to what Gunnar said (issue being related to the newly introduced cloud-based chat).

Answer (score 1):

Skype has introduced a cloud-based group chat system, which requires Skype 4.3. Possibly that has something to do with it.

Comment: Hmm, this might interfere with something. It's only strange that certain group chats work and others not, depending on the people.

Comment: Sorry, have no reputation to upvote.